# Using multiple conditions in regex

Tags: regex

I am attempting to create a regex that matches when two conditions are met:

1. URL snippet is present
2. After the snippet the number "1" must also be present (`1` does not have to be
   immediately after snippet)

Both conditions must be met for the regex to be true.

This is the regex that I have so far:

```
^https?:\/\/www\.website\.co\.uk\/brand\/
```

This matches the URL snippet. But I want the regex to include the second condition.
Therefore, if the second condition was included
This would match:  `http://www.website.co.uk/brand/AD/**1**/A_d.html`
But this would not:  `http://www.website.co.uk/brand/`

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: A positive lookahead is what you're after: `(?:.*(?=1))`, e.g. [`^https?://www\.website\.co\.uk/brand/(?:.*(?=1))`](https://regex101.com/r/mW8mB1/1)

Comment: Please add the programming language (In the post and tags). If this is in Java, I can already see some problems that might not be applicable to other languages.

Comment: can you put that in an answer and explain what it does?

Comment: @Jan `.*1` has the same effect and is shorter.

Comment: @Siguza: True, but does not look so fancy, does it ;-) ?

Answer (score 2):

```
^https?:\/\/www\.website\.co\.uk\/brand\/.*1.*
```

If you have a .* in regex, you match all characters asides from newline. By padding your 1 with .* you match all regexes that have

```
http://www.website.co.uk/brand/
```

and are followed by characters with at least one `1`.

Comment: Note: the `.*` at the end can be omitted if one is only testing for a match.

Comment: ... somewhat petty-minded but it *does not match all characters* (all **but** the newline). Nevertheless, +1.